# Count how many fall within a time range based on specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to produce a formula that counts how many times and individual registers a time between a certain time range. The table below is part of the data. So, for example, I need a formula to count how many times Richard arrived between 1500 and 1800.

The table has columns headed Name, ontime and scheduled time

I have tried combining `LOOKUP` and `COUNTIFS`, but none seem to work.

```
name    on time Sched Time

James   N   1655
Robert  N   1115
Robert  N   1650
Helen   N   1130
Helen   N   1630
Richard N   1115
Richard N   1545
Richard N   1700
Colin   N   1235
Colin   N   1600
Colin   N   1725
Paul    N   1225
Paul    N   1545
Paul    N   1715
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far and what wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

With **multiple criteria** consider using *Sumproduct()*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A15="Richard")*(C1:C15>=1500)*(C1:C15<=1800))
```

[image]